# Not getting how to resolve "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following table:

Sample Data:

```
e_id e_ctry e_grp_id e_loc_nbr e_loc_id e_sal
=============================================
111  03     65       889        03      10000
131  01     67       009        09      8000
152  02     12       545        09      17000
155  04     55       778        09      33000
115  04     55       778        09      33000
156  04     55       778        09      33000 
177  03     65       889        03      14000
122  03     65       889        03      14000
141  03     65       889        03      17000
171  03     65       889        03      14000
```

Trying the following Code:

```
d_tbl = self.emp_d[['e_id','e_ctry','e_grp_id','e_loc_nbr','e_loc_id','e_sal']].drop_duplicates()


def e_c_rslt(self):
    e_c_data = self.d_tbl[(self.d_tbl['e_loc_id']==1) ][['e_id','e_ctry','e_grp_id','e_loc_nbr','e_sal']]
    e_c_grpd = e_c_data.groupby([e_id','e_grp_id','e_ctry']).e_sal.nunique().reset_index() 
    rslt_ac9b=e_c_grpd[e_c_grpd.e_sal>15000]
```

but keep on getting the below error message:

```
e_c_grpd = e_c_data.groupby([e_id','e_grp_id','e_ctry']).e_sal.nunique().reset_index() 

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2866, in nunique
    res = out if ids[0] != -1 else out[1:]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Not getting what am I doing wrong?

Expected O/P:

```
e_id e_ctry e_grp_id  e_sal
===========================
111  03     65       10000
177  03     65       14000
122  03     65       14000
141  03     65       17000
171  03     65       14000
```

The requirement is to collect `['e_id', 'e_ctry', 'e_grp_id']` if `e_sal>15000` and wherever there's different `e_sal` for the same `'e_ctry', 'e_grp_id'`.

Update_1:

After printing `print(e_c_data)` getting:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [e_id,e_ctry,e_grp_id,e_loc_nbr,e_sal]
Index: []
```

Comment: What's desired output?

Comment: @U9-Forward Have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message is telling you that the object you're indexing into has size 0-- in other words, it's empty.  Why would it be empty?  Well, you could put in `print`s to find out where it happens, or we can just look at your frame:

```
e_id e_ctry e_grp_id e_loc_nbr e_loc_id e_sal
=============================================
111  03     65       889        03      10000
131  01     67       009        09      8000
```

Assuming this is representative, note that your e_loc_id column starts with a 0.  But if it's an integer, it wouldn't: those show up without leading zeros.  Which means you must have strings:

```
In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2], "B": ['01', '02']})

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   A   B
0  1  01
1  2  02

In [15]: df.dtypes
Out[15]: 
A     int64
B    object
dtype: object
```

But if your e_loc_ds are strings, this comparison will never succeed:

```
self.d_tbl['e_loc_id']==1
```

and so e_c_data is empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Updated my question with the result.